# Facebook Integration in android giving compile() error

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to add facebook login. I am following the facebook [quick starts](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/1225959640768598/?platform=android). But I am getting the following error.

`

```
Error:(24, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'FacebookAdd' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>`
```

and the **gradle.build** files.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.psycho.ayush.facebookadd"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

     dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    }
```

P.S. I have gone through almost every question related to this on this site.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two dependencies sections please try this:

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
   compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    }
```

and remove this

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'}
```